Holomorphic Sectional Curvature Determines Riemannian Curvature Tensor
I'm reading Riemannian Submersions, Riemannian Maps in Hermitian Geometry, and their Applications by Bayram Şahin. I have a problem when reading the claim in Chapter 3, page 80:

A simply connected complete Kähler manifold of constant holomorphic sectional curvature $c$ is called a complex space form, denoted by $M(c)$. The curvature tensor of $M(c)$ is
$$R(X, Y)Z = \frac c4 (\langle Y, Z\rangle X − \langle X, Z\rangle Y + \langle JY, Z\rangle JX − \langle JX, Z\rangle JY + 2\langle X, JY\rangle JZ).$$

The author did not provide its proof, and it is not very obvious to me.
I know the holomorphic sectional curvature determines Riemannian curvature tensor in Kähler case. But if we want to prove the claim, we seem to need to write a explicit expression to prove that the holomorphic sectional curvature determines the Riemannian curvature tensor, which means that we need to use holomorphic sectional curvature to express $K(X,Y):=\langle R(X,Y)Y,X\rangle$ since the sectional curvature determines the Riemannian curvature tensor. For this idea, here is my attempt
$$K(X-Y,J(X-Y))+K(X+Y,J(X+Y))$$
$$=2K(X,JX)+4\langle R(X,JX)JY,Y\rangle+8\langle R(X,JY)JX,Y\rangle+2K(Y,JY).$$
Therefore, it suffices to express $\langle R(X,JX)JY,Y\rangle+2\langle R(X,JY)JX,Y\rangle.$
Or is there a simpler explanation for the claim? Any help would be appreciated!

I mean, if you already believe that the holomorphic sectional curvature (HSC) determines the whole tensor, then you just have to check that the given tensor has constant HSC. If it does, it must then be equal to your curvature tensor. If you want to calculate the curvature tensor from the HSC, you can do it by expanding $H(X + tY)$ as a polynomial in $t$ to get to the holomorphic bisectional curvature, and then again to go from there to the whole complex curvature tensor. Zheng does that in his Complex Differential Geometry book.

I was wrong in my original comment. Here is a discussion about this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79383/calculating-a-curvature-tensor-by-polarization

As well as this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370955/about-an-explicit-formula-of-the-curvature-tensor-by-holomorphic-sectional-curva

@Deane Thanks! The answers in the link are very useful. :)

@GunnarÞórMagnússon Thanks for the comment. I also got the final explicit expression myself. I forgot to expand $H(X+JY)$ and $H(X-JY)$ at first.
